# Binding custom control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

I have a custom control which is working fine but I would like to move the binding of the parts from the Xaml Style back into the code so that my style only contains layout information. For example how would I set the IsChecked programmatically? Below is my current Xaml for it.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="PART_EnabledCheck"  Margin="0,3,3,3" 
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnabledCheck, Mode=TwoWay, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able set the binding like this:

```
checkBox.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("EnabledCheck")
{
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
    RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.TemplatedParent)
});
```